# Closed subset of $L^1([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I want to show this:

> Consider $L^{1}([0,1])$ and $L^{2}([0,1])$, and
>   $$G=\left\{ f \;\middle\vert\; \int_{0}^{1} |f|^2 \,dm \leq n \right\}\subseteq L^{2}([0,1]),$$  for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $G$ is closed in $L^{1}([0,1])$ with the norm of $L^{1}([0,1])$. The measure being used here is Lebesgue measure.

I tried Minkowski and Hölder, but got nothing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/184b3c7a-81a5-4fd1-b032-3a73f00f1b6b/view-source) how I edited your question.[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 4):

It's enough to show that $G$ is sequentially closed: let $(f_k,k\geqslant 1)$ be a sequence of elements of $G$, converging in $L^1$ to some $f$. Extracting a subsequence which converges almost everywhere, and using Fatou's lemma, we are done.

Comment: You are welcome.