# $L^2$ and $L^1$ space relationship

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Got an interesting question here.

Show that $A_n = \{f \in L^1[0,1] : \int |f|^2 \leq n\}$ is nowhere dense (in $L^1$).

I can't seem to find the correct function that does the trick here.

Thoughts?

Comment: So you mean nowhere dense as a subset of $L^1$, not as a subset of $L^2$?

Comment: I assume everything refers to the $L^1$ space as mentioned in the set notation. Can't say for sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The set $A_n$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465274/closed-subset-of-l10-1?rq=1), hence we only have to show that it has an empty interior. Suppose not: there is a function $f_0$ and $\delta\gt 0$ such that 
$\lVert g-f_0\rVert_1\lt \delta$ implies that $g\in A_n$.
To get a contradiction, we have to find a sequence $(g_k)\subset\mathbb L^2$ such that $\lVert g_k\rVert_2\to \infty$ and $\lVert g_k\rVert_1\to 0$. For example, $g_k:=a_k\chi_{(0,k^{-1})}$ with $a_k/k\to 0$ but $a_k/\sqrt k\to \infty$.

Comment: Yes I know. But what is that sequence?

Comment: See edit. ${}{}{}$

Comment: What is $a_k$ here?

Comment: A real number. We can take $a_k=k^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in (1/2,1)$.